# What is "\$@" in ssh command

Tags: ssh

I am trying to do some ssh based git clone. While at it, I ran into a ssh command syntax some of which I don't understand:

```
ssh -i $pwd/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "\$@"
```

What is this "\$@"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`$@` means [all the parameters passed to the script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9994295/9035237), but this may be interpretted too early.

For passing it originally to ssh params, you need to escape it, and the simplest way is to escape the `$` sign, which results in `"\$@"`.